# How Do I Change a "style" Image in a Website Using a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to figure out how to change images of a website using chrome extensions that aren't just ones with "src" attributes. In my case, I am trying to change the logo on https://www.foxnews.com/ and I can see when I inspect and look in "styles" that it is the "background-image" property. The problem is that when I set it to my own image (using methods that have worked elsewhere before), nothing happens. I can change the "background-size" and "background-color", but the image will not budge. Can someone please provide a solution?

Here is my code so far:
manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "ChromeExtension",
    "description": "E",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["*.jpg","*.JPG"],
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
    ],
    
    "permissions": ["storage","activeTab","scripting"],

    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.foxnews.com/"],
            "js":["fNews.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

and fNews.js:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("logo")[0].style.backgroundColor = '#3aa757';
document.getElementsByClassName("logo")[0].setAttribute('href','https://www.cnn.com/');
document.getElementsByClassName("logo")[0].style.backgroundSize = '50%';
document.getElementsByClassName("logo")[0].style.backgroundImage = 'chrome-extension://igdebagnkjaemmchleldelgggjpbngkl/Duck.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[backgroundImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) may contain several types of content so we need to use `url()` here:

```js
document.querySelector('.logo').style.backgroundImage =
  `url("${ chrome.runtime.getURL('Duck.jpg') }");`
```

And we've used `chrome.runtime.getURL` instead of hard-coding the id of the extension.

Comment: Yeah just putting url() around my link fixed the problem. I can't believe it was such a simple solution that I didn't think of when I saw the image already in place had it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try injecting a css file with the changes directly into the css itself, this would override the current page css.

Create a css file with your styles for the logo:

```
.logo{
  background-image: url('...');
  background-color: #3aa757;
  background-size: 50%;
}
```

Then in your js script inject it to the page:

```
window.onload = async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
    
    // inject css
    await chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        files: ['logo.css'],
    });
}
```

And add permissions to manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "....",
...
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs" ,
    "scripting"
  ],
...
}
```

Comment: So I tried implementing what you said but I got the error that "TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined" for the second line of the JS. Keep in mind that I am clueless on how any of the CSS injecting works at the moment, but can you tell me how to fix this error in the meantime? Thanks for responding so quickly btw much appreciated.

Comment: I know you already fixed the issue, but if you feel the need to inject anything in the future, I guess this could be useful. I edited the comment to add the permissions needed to run the code posted, the error is because the required permissions are not set in the manifest. You can check the google docs about the injection (scripting) API: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/